# A question on (odd) perfect numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, functional-inequalities, perfect-numbers

(Note: This has been cross-posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203859).)

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the (classical) sum of the divisors of $x$.

A number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ is called *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$.

An *even* perfect number $U$ is said to be given in *Euclidean* form if $U=(2^p - 1){2^{p-1}}$ (where $2^p - 1$ is called the *Mersenne* prime).  On the other hand, an *odd* perfect number $L$ is said to be given in *Eulerian* form if $L = {q^k}{n^2}$ (where $q$ is called the *Euler* prime).

Notice that for even perfect numbers, trivially we have $1 < 2^p - 1$ (where $1$ is the exponent of the Mersenne prime $2^p - 1$).

Does a similar statement hold for odd perfect numbers?  That is, does $k < q$ always hold?

Comment: Note that $k < q$ is true when $n < q$, as then we have $1 = k < n < q$.  However, [Brown](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) has recently announced a proof for the inequality $q < n$.

Comment: Trivially, $k < q$ always holds when $k=1$.

Answer (score 1):

(The following answer has also been posted to [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/203859).)

This is only a partial answer.  I just wanted to collect some of my recent thoughts on this problem.

Suppose to the contrary that $q \leq k$.  Since $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $q$ is prime, we have $q \geq 5$, which then implies that $k \geq 5$.  (That is, $k=1$ does not hold when $q \leq k$.)

We compute bounds for the abundancy index
$$I(q^k) = \dfrac{q^{k+1} - 1}{{q^k}(q - 1)} = \dfrac{q}{q - 1} - \dfrac{1}{q - 1}\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{1}{q}\bigg)^k$$
which is known to lie in the range $(1, 5/4)$ when $k \neq 1$.  ([Details are in this MSE question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2130737))  The abundancy index of $q^k$ has no [global maxima](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize%20q%2F(q%20-%201)%20-%20(1%2F(q%20-%201))(1%2Fq)%5Ek%20for%20q%20%3C%3D%20k) nor [global minima](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Minimize%20q%2F(q%20-%201)%20-%20(1%2F(q%20-%201))(1%2Fq)%5Ek%20for%20q%20%3C%3D%20k) for $q \leq k$.  Hence we proceed as follows:

We have the simultaneous inequalities
**(1)** $\dfrac{k}{k - 1} - \dfrac{1}{q - 1}\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{1}{q}\bigg)^k \leq I(q^k) < \dfrac{5}{4}$ 
and
**(2)** $1 < I(q^k) \leq \dfrac{q}{q - 1} - \dfrac{1}{k - 1}\cdot\bigg(\dfrac{1}{k}\bigg)^k,$ 
which can then be solved for $q$ in terms of $k$.

I tried using WolframAlpha, but it is returning a "**Standard computation time exceeded...**" message on both inequalities [**(1)**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20k%2F(k%20-%201)%20-%20(1%2F(q%20-%201))(1%2Fq)%5Ek%20%3C%205%2F4%20for%20q%20in%20terms%20of%20k) and [**(2)**](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%20q%2F(q%20-%201)%20-%20(1%2F(k%20-%201))(1%2Fk)%5Ek%20%3E%201%20for%20q%20in%20terms%20of%20k).

On the other hand, if we just assume $q = k$, then we still have that $k=1$ does not hold, as well as the stronger bound
$$I(q^q) = \dfrac{q^{q+1} - 1}{{q^q}(q - 1)} \leq \dfrac{3906}{3125} = 1.24992.$$
(Computation of this upper bound in WolframAlpha [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize%20q%2F(q%20-%201)%20-%20(1%2F(q%20-%201))(1%2Fq)%5Eq%20for%20q%20%3E%3D%205).)

**Added March 04 2017 (Manila time)**

Following the methodology in this [paper](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.pdf), we get the lower bound
$$I(q^q) + I(n^2) \geq 2\cdot\dfrac{3125}{3906} + \dfrac{3906}{3125} = \dfrac{17394043}{6103125} \approx 2.850022406554.$$

Since $k \neq 1$, we have the upper bound
$$\dfrac{3q^2 + 2q + 1}{q(q+1)} = 3 - \dfrac{q - 1}{q(q+1)} > I(q^q) + I(n^2).$$

[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3%20-%2017394043%2F6103125%20%3E%20(q%20-%201)%2F(q(q%2B1))) then gives the trivial lower bound
$$q > \dfrac{3125}{781} \approx 4.0012804.$$