# Can this heuristic on odd perfect numbers be made rigorous?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, conjectures, divisor-sum, perfect-numbers

> **Can this heuristic on odd perfect numbers be made rigorous <s>using the "Axiom of Choice"</s>?**

*Preliminaries*

Euler showed that an odd perfect number, if one exists, must take the form $N=q^k n^2$ where $q$ is prime with $q \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  (It follows that $q \geq 5$.)

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the sum of the divisors of $x \in \mathbb{N}$.  Then by definition,
$$\sigma(q^k)\sigma(n^2) = \sigma(q^k n^2) = \sigma(N) = 2N = 2 q^k n^2$$
from which it follows that
$$I(q^k)I(n^2) = \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k}\cdot\dfrac{\sigma(n^2)}{n^2} = 2$$
where $I(x)=\sigma(x)/x$ is the *abundancy index* of $x$.

*Numerics*

By a well-known formula for the sum of divisors of a prime power, we have
$$I(q^k) = \dfrac{\sigma(q^k)}{q^k} = \dfrac{q^{k+1} - 1}{{q^k}(q - 1)}.$$

This is bounded by
$$\dfrac{q+1}{q} = I(q) \leq I(q^k) < \dfrac{q^{k+1}}{{q^k}(q - 1)} = \dfrac{q}{q - 1}.$$

Now, note that, when $k=1$, we have the bounds
$$1 < I(q^k) = \dfrac{q+1}{q} = 1 + \dfrac{1}{q} \leq 1 + \dfrac{1}{5} = \dfrac{6}{5},$$
from which it follows that
$$\dfrac{5}{3} \leq I(n^2) = \dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} = \dfrac{2}{I(q)} < 2.$$

Additionally, when $k>1$, we have the bounds
$$1 < I(q^k) < \dfrac{q}{q - 1}.$$
Since
$$\dfrac{q}{q - 1} = \dfrac{1}{1 - (1/q)}$$
we obtain
$$q \geq 5 \iff 1/q \leq 1/5 \iff 1 - (1/q) \geq 4/5 \iff \dfrac{1}{1 - (1/q)} \leq 5/4$$
so that
$$1 < I(q^k) < \dfrac{q}{q - 1} \leq \dfrac{5}{4}.$$

This then implies that
$$\dfrac{8}{5} < I(n^2) = \dfrac{2}{I(q^k)} < 2.$$

*Implications*

Note that we have proved the following implications:

> **(1)** If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with $k=1$, then $I(n^2) \geq 5/3$.
>
> **(2)** If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with $k>1$, then $I(n^2) > 8/5$.

*Contrapositives*

> **(3)** *Contrapositive of* **(1)** If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with $I(n^2) < 5/3$, then $k>1$.
>
> **(4)** *Contrapositive of* **(2)** If $N=q^k n^2$ is an odd perfect number with $I(n^2) \leq 8/5$, then $k=1$.

**Analysis**

By **(3)** and **(2)**, we have
$$I(n^2) < 5/3 \implies k>1 \implies I(n^2) > 8/5 \implies 8/5 < I(n^2) < 5/3$$
resulting in no contradiction, since ${8}\cdot{3} = 24 < 25 = {5}\cdot{5}$.

By **(4)** and **(1)**, we get
$$I(n^2) \leq 8/5 \implies k=1 \implies I(n^2) \geq 5/3 \implies 5/3 \leq I(n^2) \leq 8/5$$
resulting in a contradiction, since ${5}\cdot{5}= 25 \nleq 24 = {8}\cdot{3}$.

This implies that $I(n^2) > 8/5$ is unconditionally true.

Now here is the heuristic:

**Heuristic**

If we <s>use the "Axiom of Choice" and</s> identify the lower bound $I(n^2) \geq 5/3$ with $k=1$ and similarly identify the lower bound $I(n^2) > 8/5$ with $k>1$, and since assuming the negation of the latter lower bound contradicts **(4)** and **(1)** above, does this mean that we can predict $k>1$ to be true?

That is, can we "assume" or prove that the following biconditionals hold?
$$k=1 \iff I(n^2) \geq 5/3$$
$$k>1 \iff I(n^2) > 8/5$$

Comment: How exactly do you plan to use the axiom of choice? It's not a magic want, it's a specific principle.

Comment: I don't see what the axiom of choice would have to do with anything you wrote...

Comment: By "using the Axiom of Choice", I meant something along the lines of:  "Identify $k=1$ with $\ldots$, identify $k>1$ with $\ldots$, and then show that one set of assumptions leads to a contradiction, and hence choose the one that does not".

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris (1) I don't understand what you mean by "Identify $k=1$ with . . ." (2) Showing that one thing leads to a contradiction, and so deducing the other, isn't the axiom of choice - it's just proof by contradiction.

Comment: Hmmmm, perhaps I have just poorly expressed myself.  I'll let the question stand, and will come back to it with the required edits ASAP.

Comment: I have crossed out the previous references to AC in the title and body of the question.  Please let me know if the question makes sense to you now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do nothing of the sort, and the axiom of choice plays no role here.

Let's ignore the specific math leading up to the "Analysis" part, and just look at the logic of what you're trying to do. (In particular, I make no claim about whether said math is correct.)

You have two numbers, "$k$" and "$I=I(n^2)$," that you care about; and you know $$k\ge 1,\quad k=1\implies I\ge{5\over 3},\quad\mbox{ and }\quad k>1\implies I>{8\over 5}.$$ All this lets you conclude is that $I<{5\over 3}$  implies $k>1$. If $I\ge{5\over 3}$, *you can't conclude anything* - both "$k=17$, $I=17$" and "$k=1, I=17$" satisfy the three facts above. In particular, from what you know so far there is no way to identify $k=1$ with $I\ge{5\over 3}$. (It's always a good idea to think through a few specific examples before trying to jump to a conclusion.)

You are trying to invoke the axiom of choice to get around a logical gap - that you can't conclude the converse of a statement from the statement. But this isn't a thing the axiom of choice does.

---

EDIT: Note that by [Shoenfield absoluteness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness#Shoenfield.27s_absoluteness_theorem) (actually that's massive overkill but oh well), the truth of Sorli's conjecture can't possibly depend on the axiom of choice: if there is a proof using AC, there is also a proof not using AC. (Incidentally, this doesn't mean that the proof via AC might be easier to find, just that AC won't ultimately be necessary.) I strongly suspect that the same goes for each of the Millennium problems - indeed $P=NP$, Birch Swinnerton-Dyer, and Navier-Stokes are all not hard to cast in arithmetic terms - but I am worried about the Hodge Conjecture on the general principle that it looks scary to me (but it also does look $\Pi^1_2$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Noah.  $I=17$ surely cannot happen for $n^2$ since $I$ is the abundancy index?  ($I(x) = \sigma(x)/x$...) (And $n^2$ is deficient, being a proper factor of the perfect number $N = q^k n^2$...)

Comment: Any way, I do get your point now Noah.  This is just another one of my naive attempts to reconstruct what my M. Sc. adviser once told me about a possibility of resolving Sorli's Conjecture via AC.  At any rate, I am now convinced that it cannot be done.  Thanks again!

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris I've added a bit to my answer about AC which you might find interesting.

Comment: No worries, I perfectly understood!  =)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out!  I will check out Shoenfield absoluteness.  =)